# .net core how to add Content-range to header

Tags: .net-core, odata

I'm having no luck find out how to add Content-Range to the header of my odata requests. My api requires a format as such for paging:

```
Content-Range: posts 0-24/319
```

The closest thing I can find is HTTP Byte Range Support. From here: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/23/asp-net-web-api-and-http-byte-range-support/ . The OP says a post will be written about [Queryable] which is supposed to add support for paging, but I have yet to see any info on this.

```
        [EnableQuery]
        [ODataRoute]
        public IActionResult Get(ODataQueryOptions<HC_PortalActivity> 
         options)
        {

            return Ok(Db.HC_PortalActivity_Collection);
        }
```

Comment: Please explain where you are trying to add the header? Before it gets to your controller method? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
  public static void IncludeContentRange<T>(ODataQueryOptions<T> options, HttpRequest context)
        {
            var range = options.Request.Query["range"][0].Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Split(',');
            var q = from x in Db.HC_PortalActivity_Collection
                    select x;

            var headerValue = string.Format("{0} {1}-{2}/{3}", options.Context.NavigationSource.Name.ToLower(), range[0], range[1], q.Count());
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Range");
            context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", headerValue);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `Content-Range` header to your `HttpRequest.Content` object:

```
request.Content.Headers.ContentRange = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentRangeHeaderValue(0, 24, 319);

request.Content.Headers.ContentRange.Unit = "posts";
```

Remember to set the `Unit` otherwise it will default to `bytes'

**EDIT**

The `Content` property is only available on the `HttpRequestMessage` class, not the `HttpRequest` class. So you will need to create one to be able to access the `ContentRange` property.

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
... // as above
```

Assuming you are using a `HttpClient` to send your request you can pass the request in the `SendAsync` method

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
... // other setup

httpClient.SendAsync(request);
```

Comment: Does this apply for .net core I'm having trouble accessing HttpRequest.Content

Comment: Apologies. The property is on a HttpRequestMessage class (not the HttpRequest class) so you need to create one of them for your message. I've updated my answer to add this.

Comment: I've updated my question to include what my Controller action looks like.

Answer (score 0):

If you are into an ASP.NET Core controller and want to return the 'Content-Range' header for clients, you can use `Response` property from `ControllerBase`.

```cs
base.Response.Headers.ContentRange = "posts 0-24/319";
```