# Set Content-Range in .Net Core middleware

Tags: http, asp.net-core, http-headers

I use react-admin on my frontend application which needs the Content-Range header set for each api endpoint that returns a list of elements. My api is an ASP .Net Core application. I know that you can set the Content-Range header in the way shown at this answer: [.net core how to add Content-range to header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289657/net-core-how-to-add-content-range-to-header), but I'd like to set it in a way that it will be applied for all endpoints.
How can I achieve this by using a middleware or other methods?

Answer (score 0):

Through the HttpContext we can access the Response an the Response class has an `OnStarting()` method that executes right before starting to write anything in the boy of the request. The method accepts a callback function with the specific purpose of performing whatever task must be performed before the body is written :

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(() =>
    {
        context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", "xxxx");
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    });
    await next();
});
app.UseMvc();
```

Comment: My problem with this is that I don't know the number of elements in the response body without parsing it.